# How do you return only a group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following script of which I want a simple group by:

```
# import the pandas module
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\temp\test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
# Create an example dataframe
raw_data = {'Date': ['2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13','2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13'],
        'Portfolio': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'Duration': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'Yield': [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'])

dft = df.groupby(['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'], as_index =False)
```

This creates a pandas group by object.

I then want to output this to excel:

```
dft.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)
writer.save()
```

However it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_excel' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Why would I need a apply?  I only want the group by results to remove duplicates.

Comment: Try `dft.apply(lambda x: x.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False))`

Comment: @EdChum That does not work it returns the 6 Rows for Portfolio 'C'

Comment: What is your intention here? a `groupby` is intended for aggregations on groups why don't you just set the index to those columns and output to excel?

Comment: @EdChum The intention is to return data without duplicate rows as a DataFrame.  I SQL this would be `SELECT DATE, PORTFOLIO, DURATION, YIELD FROM DATAFRAME GROUP BYDATE, PORTFOLIO, DURATION, YIELD`

Comment: try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield']).to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)`

Comment: @EdChum I think that the `groupby` should also be made to work like this.

Comment: @toasteez a groupby object is not a dataframe, so it cannot be written to an excel file (it is an objects that holds a dataframe together with the grouping information). But, you can probably do something like this using groupby: `df.groupby(...).first().to_excel(...)` to get the first observation for each group (this is similar to the drop_duplicates)

Comment: @joris am i correct in thinking that the groupby becomes a dataframe once and action is applied such as `.sum()` or `.mean()`?

Comment: I think you should be able to iterate over `for group in df.groupby("col"):` and then hold the groups you want in list `if contidition: my_groups.append(group[1]) # this is a DataFrame` and then concat the dataframes ` pd.concat(my_groups)`.

Comment: @toasteez That is indeed a correct thinking!

Comment: With that in mind perhaps there should be a `.group()` that does the same as the drop_duplicates so that both work.

Comment: @toasteez But what should such a `group()` do? Take the first of each group as drop_duplicates does? (but for that there is `first`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed drop duplicates using `groupby`, by taking the first or the mean of each group, like:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'], as_index=False).mean()
df.groupby(['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'], as_index=False).first()
```

Note that you have to apply a function (in this case using the `mean` or `first` methods) to get back a DataFrame from the groupby object. This can then be written to excel.

But as @EdChum notes, in this case using the `drop_duplicates` method of a dataframe is the easier approach:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'])
```

Comment: Inasmuch as the dataframe consists of these four fields only you can use drop_duplicates() without any parameters.

Comment: @knagaev Indeed! In this case that is the easiest solution.